# Access C# variable from javascript function or vice versa in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a function that checks if there are numbers only in a textbox. If it doesn't pass, the program won't execute an sql insert. I, however, need to show popup with the message. The popUp function is in the javascript code, and the variable, alertString is in the server side code. How can I call the popUp function in the button click code? The page does a postback so I don't really know what to do. If anything needs to be clearer, I can post more code. I'm using visual studios 2005. The page seems to just refresh. If I return false from onclientclick, it works, but my executeinsert method won't work

Buttonclick function

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (CheckStrings()) //checkstrings funciton
        {
            Button3.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");//fails
            string script = "delayer(5000);";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ButtonAlert", script, true); 
//doesn't work if onclientlick returns true.

        }
        else
        {
...


            ExecuteInsert(dtTime, intShift, intOperator, Line1, canCode1, intCanVac1, intCanTemp1, intImage1, intSeam1, strComments1, null, null, null,
                false, null, null, false, intSKU, Line2, canCode2, intCanVac2, intCanTemp2, intSeam2, strComments2, null, intSKU2, intCoredia1, intCoredia2); 
//fails if I return false for client click
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to display a server-side variable in JavaScript, you have a lot of options.  `HiddenField`, writing the variable's value into a `RegisterClientScriptBlock`.  Those are just two.

Comment: The OnClientClick property can be set on the button... point at a Javascript function. The javascript function can do your validation for you and prevent the postback. You might also want to look into the built-in C# RegularExpressionValidator, though. It seems a better fit for the validation you are doing.

Comment: I probably need to add more code to make things clearer. I'm updating.

Comment: Remember to only include relevant code. None of the stuff in the save method is relevant outside of "it runs some check first and tries to register a client script alert" ..

Comment: ok, I updated it. If i return false using onclientclick, execute insert won't run. If checkstrings returns true, the javascript won't run because of the postback.

Comment: @user2246674 do need more code or a clearer explanation?

Comment: Less code - and then explain what doesn't work or, what works, but not as desired. `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ButtonAlert", script, true);` appears to be an attempt to show the alert, right? Now, what does "fails cause of postback" mean? That approach should work with the [Partial]PostBack model just fine (non-Web 2.0 nature aside). Does the alert show at all? Is there an error on the client? Etc.

Comment: @user2246674 It doesn't show at all. I'm using visual studios 2005. The page seems to just refresh. If I return false from onclientclick, it works, but my executeinsert method won't work.

Comment: @Garrisson Neely I've already tried that. I updated my code.

Comment: @Pete Scott What is a regularexpressionvalidator?

Comment: @kaser http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx A webcontrol that provides client- and server-side regular expression validation of a given control.